# Tokenize the mmaped string using strtok

Tags: mmap, strtok

I have mmaped a huge file containing 4k * 4k floats. Since it was an text file, I need to mmap it as char string and use. Now I need to parse floats and write into 2d array. If I tokenize it using strtok, it will not allow me to do since mmapped string is not modifiable. If I copy the string into std::string and then tokenize using getline function, it let me to do it but I feel I will lose the performance got from mmap. How do I optimally solve this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some different solutions, but you will have to benchmark to find out which one is the best for you. It's not always clear that `mmap()`ing a file and processing the memory-mapped pages directly is the best solution. Especially if you make a single sequential pass through the file, a loop that `read()`s pieces at a time into a buffer can be faster, even if you use `madvise()` together with `mmap()`. Again, benchmark if you want to know what is fastest for you.

Some solutions you might try:

- `mmap()` with `MAP_WRITE` and `MAP_PRIVATE` and then use your existing `strtok()` code. This will allow `strtok()` to write the `NUL` bytes it wants to write, without having those changes be reflected in the file. If you choose this solution, you should probably call `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` on the parts of the file you have already processed, else memory usage will grow linearly.
- Implement your own variant of `strtok()` that returns the length of the matched token instead of a `NUL`-terminated string. It's not difficult, using `memchr()`. This way you don't need to modify the memory. You might then need to pass the resulting tokens to functions that take a string and a length instead of a `NUL`-terminated string. There aren't many such functions in the C library, but even so you might be able to get away with calling functions like `strtod()` if the tokens are guaranteed to end in some non-digit delimiter. Or you can copy them into a small stack-allocated buffer (they're floats, they can't be that long, right?)
- Use a `read()`-and-process loop instead of `mmap()`.

Comment: Very helpful answer! I have almost the exact same problem as the asker but already have the `read()`-and-process loop and was wondering if `mmap()` would help, this is definitely going to save me some work.